# Maven how to ignore artifact descriptor?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, build-dependencies

Is there a way to instruct Maven to not look for **artifact descriptor** for some dependencies? 
I am struggling with this problem :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project zws-consumer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.etech.zws:zws-consumer:jar:2.9.28.RC1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ptv:xlocate-cxf-client:jar:1.20.1.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ptv:xlocate-cxf-client:jar:1.20.1.3: Could not find artifact com.ptvag.xserver.build:xserver-parent:pom:1.20.1.0 in artifactory-etech-releases (https://artifactory.etech.delivery/artifactory/etech/releases/) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project zws-consumer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.etech.zws:zws-consumer:jar:2.9.28.RC1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ptv:xlocate-cxf-client:jar:1.20.1.3
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
...
```

So the probelm seems clear:

```
Could not find artifact com.ptvag.xserver.build:xserver-parent:pom:1.20.1.0 in artifactory-etech-releases (https://artifactory.etech.delivery/artifactory/etech/releases/)
```

The problem is when I look at the repository `https://artifactory.etech.delivery/artifactory/etech/releases/` there isn't any dependency with this name `com.ptvag.xserver.build:xserver-parent`but all other dependencies are there.

Since it just about artifact description, is there a way to tell maven to ignore that. All dependencies with that description are in my `.m2` but the command `mvn clean install` fails because of this error.

The build passed 2 days ago, but I am trying to migrate the project from jdk8 to 11 and I am facing this issue since 1 day.

Related dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ptv</groupId>
        <artifactId>xlocate-cxf-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ptv</groupId>
        <artifactId>xroute-cxf-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ptv</groupId>
        <artifactId>xtour-cxf-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see the `groupId` of those dependencies is `com.ptv` but the exception is about `com.ptvag`. I'm a little confused because on the repository there isn't a `com.ptvag` groupId.

**EDIT**

After some searches I found where that dependency was, please look below: 
[image]

Now I don't understand why maven try to download it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing a parent pom of one of your dependencies. Without this parent pom, it is not possible to build the tree of all transitive dependencies (the parent pom might contain dependencies or dependencyManagement entries). So the build does not work.

The artifact `com.ptv:xlocate-cxf-client:jar:1.20.1.3` is a (transitive) dependency of your project. Look there, if the described POM is the parent of this project. If so, you need it for the build.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, so if I understand, getting the artifacts (.jar) with their versions isn't enough, I also need the parent pom?

Comment: You need the parent poms of all dependencies, including transitive ones. Usually, these should all exist in the repository where you draw your artifacts from. Otherwise you need to research the special cases.

Comment: So, I am stuck because I don't see where I can't find the parent's pom, I can only have the .jar artifacts :'(

Comment: Where did you get the jars from?

Comment: It's a legacy project I inherited on my company that I try to migrate to jdk11 though I absolutely don't know where did they find these jars.

Comment: How did this work before? It does not look like something that should change when you move from Java 8 to 11.

Comment: I am also wondering, I tried to rollabck but now even with java 8 it no longer works.

Comment: I edited the post, I found extra information but the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the dependency like this:

```xml
    <project>
      ...
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.etech.zws</groupId>
          <artifactId>zws-consumer</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.ptvag.xserver.build</groupId>
              <artifactId>xserver-parent</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

But if maven is trying to resolve the dependency than it's most likely needed by some parts of the build/project.

You should somehow get `com.ptvag.xserver.build:xserver-parent:pom:1.20.1.0`. If it's not in your repositories you can install it manually with `mvn install` if you have the pom.xml

Comment: It is not a dependency, but a parent pom.

Comment: Runing `mvn install` will not solve the problem because those dependencies are not in the maven central repo